# Abrir un Form con el patron Singleton (Duda Teorica)

Tags: c#, formularios

Mi duda es la siguiente. Tengo 6 formularios que deseo abrir cada uno solo una vez. Tengo entonces que implemetar el codigo para cada uno de ellos, o existe la posibilidad de que lo pueda hacer generico para cualquier formulario para poder reutilizar codigo. Gracias. Este es mi codigo que funciona OK, para uno de mis formularios que se llama Curva.

```
public class AbrirForm
{
    private static Curva miformulario = null;
    private AbrirForm() { }

    public static Curva Formulario()
    {
       if(miformulario == null || miformulario.IsDisposed == true)
       {
          miformulario = new Curva();
       }

       return miformulario;   
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Curva x = AbrirForm.Formulario();
   x.Show();
}
```

Comment: de qué lenguaje estamos hablando? parece c#

Comment: *Tengo entonces que implemetar el codigo para cada uno de ellos, o existe la posibilidad de que lo pueda hacer generico* -> Los formularios son iguales? Si son diferentes obviamente cada uno necesitará su implementación, todo depende de qué vayan a tener esos formularios y cómo los uses, sin ver exactamente lo que tienen es difícil poder responder a esa pregunta

Comment: Disculpa el lenguaje que utilizo es C#.

Comment: @Andres Imagino que lo que dices es WindowsForm?? solo utiliza un UserControl un formulario que herede de este y lo llamas con tus aditamento que requieras

Comment: Los 6 formularios han de estar abiertos a la vez?

Comment: Si. Es WinForm en lo que trabajo. No son formularios MIDI, por lo que no puedo utilizar la herencia, tendria que cambiar todo el proycto.si lo realizo de esa manera. Gracias por sus comentarios

Answer (score 0):

La solución después de un largo tiempo fue la siguiente. La comparto por si ha alguien le puede servir. De esta manera se puede abrir cualquier formulario solo una vez.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FormUnaVez<Formulario2>.Abrir().Show();
}

public class FormUnaVez<T> where T: new()
{
   private static T instancia = default(T);    

   public static T Abrir()
   {
      Form frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is T);

            if (frm == null)
                instancia = new T();
            else
                frm.BringToFront();

            return instancia;
   }
}
```